# JMETER - How to handle payment method

Tags: jmeter, payment, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

JMETER - How to handle payment method.
In our website one paypal payment method is added and I want to fill it and submit the form (after completing all prerequisite).

During test recording also the section of Payment Method was BLANK.

Any information??

Answer (score 0):

If you performed the recording using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it might be the case that your browser didn't execute the request to paypal due to i.e. [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) as you previously visited paypal page and browser detects mismatch between the original paypal certificate and the [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate generated by JMeter allowing it to intercept and decrypt the secure traffic.

Try completely [cleaning your browser history](https://www.howtogeek.com/304218/how-to-clear-your-history-in-any-browser/), re-installing JMeter's certificate as per **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the aforementioned HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation chapter and you should be able to record the request to the payment gateway and replay it (after [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters)

Alternative way of recording a JMeter test is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

And last but not the least: don't use production configuration as you will loose you real money very quickly, consider using [sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) instead. Moreover I don't think you should be testing the paypal payment, you should rather focus on your application functionality